# No se reconoce speech recognition python (error)

Tags: python

He instalado speech recognition python en visual studio con el comando `pip install speechrecognition`, pero al momento de importar la librería me bota el error y me dice que no la reconoce.

He mirado si la he instalado correctamente con el comando `pip show speec recognition` y me da toda la información correctamente.

Lo he instalado y vuelto a instalar y aun así me sigue sin reconocer el speech recognition al importarlo. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Estas usando `import speech_recognition`?